# Repeater Checkbox never being seen as checked

Tags: c#, repeater

I'm trying to see which `checkbox` is selected and which isn't (just a row of items and it's a yes I am or not)

The HTML markup I have is :

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptProducts" OnItemDataBound="rptProducts_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProdType") %> </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProdName") %>: 
              <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbSelected" Text="Yes" />
              <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtGroupName"></asp:TextBox>
          </div>
        </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code:

```
if (rptProducts.Items.Count > 0)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < rptProducts.Items.Count; count++)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptProducts.Items)
        {
            CheckBox ch = item.FindControl("cbSelected") as CheckBox;
            TextBox tb = item.FindControl("tbGroupName") as TextBox;
            if (ch.Checked)
            {
                if (selectedRB == "")
                {
                    selectedRB = tb.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedRB = selectedRB + "," + tb.Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it always seems to skip over `´if (ch.Checked)´` as if it's never checked.

A couple of edits from the comments. This is being run on a button click.   `protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

The repeater is bound and displaying fine and has the right values in the textbox txtGroupName

Comment: Where is the iteration code being executed? On form submit?

Comment: When you debug what does ch contain?

Comment: Are you sure `FindControl` is actaully finding the control?  Also, if they're marked as `runat="server"`, you should just be able, in the code behind, to say `cbSelected.Checked`.

Comment: How did you bind data to **Repeater** control? Please tell us in which  event you are binding and where you want to retrieve.

Comment: @ToastyMallows Not as long as it is inside the repeater. Most likely the repeater is bound to new data and therefore no checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely **rptProducts** is re-binded after post back. If so, you can make sure binding doesn't happen again by using **IsPostBack**.

For example,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!IsPostBack) {
     rptProducts.DataSource = (Some Data)
     rptProducts.DataBind();
  }
}
```